# How to add Android Studio to the Dash?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, android-studio

i am just installing android studio using following command:

```
cd android-studio/bin
then ./studio.sh,
```

but it does not install permanently , i am just close terminal android studio is also closed.
please tell me how to install android studio

Answer (score 10):

First, go to the installation directory, and fire it up with `./studio.sh`

---

#### For >= v2.0

There is an option to add a shortcut in Android Studio's "main menu" (option highlighted in blue):

[image]

---

#### For < v2.0

There is an option to add a shortcut in Android Studio's "main menu":

[image]

---

3) To open it in the future, just search for "android studio" in the Dash:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to > *Tools* in Android Studio and there is an option to Create Desktop Entry. Just click it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create launcher shortcut for any application by creating desktop configuration file in  `/usr/share/applications/`

In your case follow this steps to add launcher shortcut for android studio..

**Step 1**:launch gedit from terminal with root previlage by running following command

```
$sudo gedit
```

**Step 2:** Add following lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AndroidStudio
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.sh(give your Andriod studio path)
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/google/android-studio/bin/studio.png(give your Andriod studio icon path)
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=AndroidStudio
```

**Step 3** : Save the file at `/usr/share/applications/` with name `AndroidStudio.desktop`

from now just search for Android studio from dash or lock to launch pad on first start or create a desktop shortcut. This way you can create launcher shortcut to any application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my android-studio.desktop file. Its working after adding bash -i before program path.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Exec=bash -i "/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Icon=/home/user/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
```